# How to load a local HTML file using WebView in JavaFX

Tags: java, webview, javafx-8

I am looking for a way to display an html file in a different stage once the help button is clicked.

```
public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        if (event.getSource() == help) {
            stage = (Stage) help.getScene().getWindow();
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("help.fxml"));
            WebView browser = new WebView();
            Scene helpScene = new Scene(root);
            Stage helpStage = new Stage();
            helpStage.setTitle("Help Menu");
            helpStage.setScene(helpScene);
            URL url = getClass().getResource("readme.html");
            browser.getEngine().load(url.toExternalForm());
            helpStage.show();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is fine except that you forgot to add the webview to the scene, do

```
((Pane) helpScene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(browser);
```